# Change color of selected cell in CollectionView depends on condition

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to set gradient cell color in CollectionView for different conditions.

[image]

The conditions are set in ViewController in didSelectItemAt method:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if cellNumbers[indexPath.item] == currentNumberGuess {
            updateNumberLabel()
}
    }
```

I managed to change the color of cells in UICollectionViewCell:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    private lazy var gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        return gradientLayer
    }()

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                self.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradient, at: 0)
                label.isHidden = true
            } else {
                self.gradient.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
    }

    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

But I also need to change color of selected cell depends on cellNumbers[indexPath.item] == currentNumberGuess condition. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Remove your `override var isSelected` code.
2. Move your `gradient` definition to your ViewController and make it a function instead:

```swift
private func getGradient(for cell: UICollectionViewCell) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    gradientLayer.frame = cell.bounds

    return gradientLayer
}
```

3. Change the color in your `didSelectItemAt` function, you can get the instance of your cell like this:

```swift
private var previousGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cellNumbers[indexPath.item] == currentNumberGuess {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }

        // Clear gradient of the previously selected cell
        self.previousGradientLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

        // Update previousGradientLayer to the new gradient
        self.previousGradientLayer = self.getGradient(for: cell)

        // Your code
        cell.layer.insertSublayer(self.previousGradientLayer!, at: 0)
        label.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I try, but get Use of unresolved identifier 'gradient'

Comment: Yea, I forgot to mention that you should define `gradient` again in your view controller. I edited my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. Get error         gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'bounds'

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you are using `self` before. I edited again, please give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. But I also need to deselect previous cell, when selecting a new one. I used code                 self.gradient.removeFromSuperlayer() for this before.

Comment: You can still keep a reference of the previously inserted gradient sublayer. I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220755/discussion-between-eric-hua-and-parcker).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`closure`** for handling this.

**1.** Create a `handler` in `CollectionViewCell` and call it when `isSelected` is `true`, i.e.

```
var handler: (()->(Bool))? 

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if self.isSelected {
            if let value = self.handler?(), value {
                self.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradient, at: 0)
                label.isHidden = true
            }
        } else {
            self.gradient.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** Set the value of `handler` in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.handler = {
        return cellNumbers[indexPath.item] == currentNumberGuess
    }
    return cell
}
```

**3.** In `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` reload the cell at `indexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```